# Node.js express with mongodb calls does not finish execution

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a .post function where I am using mongodb call, something like this:

```
router.post('/insert')=>{

-findOne
// Some code
// with error return redirect('/error')

-Count
// with error return redirect('/error')

-Insert
// with error return redirect('/error') 
// with normal execution return redirect('/save')
}
```

My problem is that after this rediret, this function execution does not finish. So, if what i am checknig after findOne fails, i do not want to go inside Count or Insert

note that I am already using `return redirect()`

Edit Adding some code:

```
router.post('/insert_article', common.restrict, (req, res) => {
db.findOne({
        _id: root_id
    },(err, item) => {
            if (item.language !== req.body.form_language) {
                req.session.message = req.i18n.__('Language does not match');
                req.session.message_type = 'Fail!';
                return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/insert');
            }
    })

 db.insert(doc, (err, newDoc) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error inserting document: ' + err);

                } else {
                  //some stuff
                  req.session.message = req.i18n.__('New article successfully created');
                  req.session.message_type = 'success';

                    // redirect to new doc
                  res.redirect(req.app_context + '/edit/' + newId);
                }
    })
}
```

I think now it is clearer, when that "language" doesnt match, i do not want to do this insert anyway, and this keep doing it

Comment: What do you mean the function execution does not finish? If it is redirecting, and if you are returning at that point, then the function must be finishing

Comment: I mean, that the execution goes inside Count and Insert mongo calls anyway, even after this return redirect

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now. Without seeing more code for how you set up the error handling and the route itself, it's hard to say. Can you include some more code?

Comment: I already added it :)

Comment: Refer to my answer below. As I suspected, you are trying to return from the overall function while executing code inside of a asynchronous callback function, which is not possible to do. If you want to continue using callbacks, the only way to prevent the other code from executing is if you include the other code in the callback as well, but this will create what is known as "callback hell". You should probably use promises instead so that you can `await` them and return from the route handler in the way that you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: With your updated code, it's clear you are trying to return from a callback, refer to the snippets below

Without more code it's hard to say but my best guess is that you are using `return redirect('/error')` inside of a callback function (such as the callback supplied to `.then` if, for example, you are using promises for your database methods), so rather than returning from the overall function, you are returning from the callback, and then continuing through the route handler. If this is the case, then it may be better to use an async route handler so you can `await` your database call instead and `return res.redirect` if something goes wrong, which will then act as you expect

Your code is doing this where you are returning from the callback, so execution inside of the route handler will continue

```
router.post('/insert_article', common.restrict, (req, res) => {
    db.kb.findOne({
        _id: root_id
    },(err, item) => {
            if (item.language !== req.body.form_language) {
                req.session.message = req.i18n.__('Language does not match');
                req.session.message_type = 'Fail!';
                // the following line will return from your callback, NOT the route handler
                return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/insert');
            }
    })
    // because you returned from the callback, code here will continue to execute
});
```

you could instead do this

```
router.post('/insert_article', common.restrict, (req, res) => {
    db.kb.findOne({
        _id: root_id
    },(err, item) => {
            if (item.language !== req.body.form_language) {
                req.session.message = req.i18n.__('Language does not match');
                req.session.message_type = 'Fail!';
                return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/insert'); // returns from callback, not the route handler
            }

            db.kb.insert(doc, (err, newDoc) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error inserting document: ' + err);
                } else {
                    //some stuff
                    req.session.message = req.i18n.__('New article successfully created');
                    req.session.message_type = 'success';

                    // redirect to new doc
                    res.redirect(req.app_context + '/edit/' + newId);
                }
                });
            }
    })
});
```

But the above approach will create "callback hell", which is callbacks inside of callbacks inside of callbacks...and so on

A better way to do this would be using promises rather than callback functions and `async/await` syntax:

```
router.post('/insert_article', common.restrict, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const item = await db.kb.findOne({ _id: root_id });
        if (item.language !== req.body.form_language) {
            req.session.message = req.i18n.__('Language does not match');
            req.session.message_type = 'Fail!';
            return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/insert');
        }

        await db.kb.insert(doc); // if there is an error, it will be caught in the catch block
        req.session.message = req.i18n.__('New article successfully created');
        req.session.message_type = 'success';
        // redirect to new doc
        return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/edit/' + newId);
    } catch (e) {
        return res.redirect(req.app_context + '/insert');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! thank you, it works! but I've been trying diferent options, and I found out that if in that 'insert' call, instead of await I use this callback, it works anyway. I mean, I just need await option in this 'findOne' call, could you explain me why? thank you!

Comment: @difegui no problem, and yeah sure. It's best not to mix promises with callbacks, but the reason it works when you just do it for `findOne` is because that is the only place where you are trying to prevent some code from happening if an error occurs. To accomplish that, you're returning from the function, and as long as you're not doing that inside of a callback function, it will return from your route handler and prevent the rest of the code from executing. In the case of the insert, there is no code afterwards which you are trying to prevent, as you are not using a return to exit early

Comment: @difegui using `async/await` here does not change the functionality of your code, but it allows you to organize your code in such a way so that you can terminate the route handler early (because you can return from the route handler, rather than from inside a separate callback function), whereas if you use a callback function, there is no way to terminate the route handler early if an error were to occur. Since you don't need to terminate early after your insert function, it doesn't matter which form you use whether it be a callback function, normal promise syntax, or `async/await` syntax

Comment: Sorry I am asking so many things, but I still not understand one thing and I didnt got it clear after searching for it... well, if we take off async and await, my code would be synchronous, right?, so, why do we make this code async first and then we pretend it is synchronous with this "await" call. I understood about callback hell and what to be in a callback function means, but I do not understand why it doesnt work properly without "async" and "await". Thank you very much

Comment: @difegui no worries, so your original code is actually not synchronous. At least, your mongodb calls are not. Passing in a callback function is also a method of writing asynchronous code, as your code is unable to wait for this function call to finish - instead, the callback function is called once the code finishes asynchronously executing

Comment: Also, using `await` does not make your code synchronous, it is simply syntactic sugar for handling promises in such a way that it looks like it has a synchronous code flow. You can read more about `async/await` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). While `await` does make your function wait for a promise to resolve, this is the same as using a `.then` block, which will also wait for the promise to resolve, but your code (somewhat) appears to synchronously pause for the code to finish in the original function, rather than in a callback

Comment: The same thing could be accomplished by returning a promise in your route handler and resolving (or rejecting) it when you want to, but `async/await` allows you to write this in a much cleaner fashion

Comment: ah ok, great, thanks! I didnt get it, because I didnt asume that these mongDB calls were async. I am just starting with node.js and mongo, so, I have many question

Comment: @difegui happy to help, and yeah it can be a little confusing at first but you'll get the hang of it. By the way, these things apply to all JavaScript code, not just Node and MongoDB. [This](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) is a great article I found which mentions and explains these different types of asynchronous code